# in ASP.NET MVC, How bind only POST variables, not GET variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, bind

I do have a situation where user would like to create an entity.
This is the `Actions` that receive the POST variables which contains the data to be bind. However there is some data with the SAME name in the URL, for instance `Action?Id=123`

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind()] Entity entity) ...
```

This is my entity POCO Class

```
public class Entity {

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string SomeData {get;set;}

}
```

When the databinder receives the request, it binds the ID from URL to the entity. It should not happen!, how can I avoid binding variables from URL (GET) and only bind variables from POST data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute filters to get the data explicitly from the form:

```
public ActionResult Post([FromForm]int id)
```

Comment: Does this filter really exists? I tried in  ASP.NET MVC 5 without success.

Comment: The filters exists in MVC6 (https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/web-api-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc-6-asp-net-5/).